# Is it possible to point IIS site's folder to ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0's development folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

I'm trying to develop using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0. To test the code, I have these options:

- Use IIS Express
- Run in console (self-hosted Kestrel)

But what I need and I was doing in ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET MVC, is to create a website in IIS and point to the development folder of my project.

I can publish my ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 project to another folder, and point my IIS site to that folder, and things start working. But this is not efficient, because for each change, even small changes I need to publish and then test it.

Why pointing IIS site to development folder of an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 project doesn't work? And what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs how to set up ASP.NET Core for IIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/ (note: iis is in this case a reverse proxy for your application).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a new article on this topic,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/development-time-iis-support

Briefly speaking, after enabling "Development time IIS support", you can debug on IIS,

[image]

Comment: I read your article, and it was truly informative. So, the only way available for IIS is to publish the project? Can we use those arguments for IIS too? I'm not using IIS Express, as it tends to differ a lot in many cases from production server. I used to use IIS only.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli the environment variables are project dependent, so setting them manually is too much trouble.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli another trick is to add a web.config to your project and configure the settings from there.

Comment: I actually asked another question regarding this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587982/how-to-debug-dotnet-exe-when-it-doesnt-find-a-dll)

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli found some new information, so rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what error you are facing but when you point your iis web application to development folder ot must be work. If it is working with same publish folder.

Please check once authorization of folder from iis

Please add error you are facing it will help more to resolve