# How to debug dotnet.exe when it doesn't find a DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 application, and when I build it, the output DLL files are created in `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0`.

When I publish it using defaults, the outputs from publish are created in `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Publish` folder.

Now when I use `dotnet` to start my application from `Publish` folder, things work just fine.

```
dotnet D:\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Publish\Project.dll
```

However, when I use `dotnet` to start my application from `netcoreapp2.0`, it complains that it can't find required DLL files.

```
dotnet D:\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Project.dll // this breaks
```

`Project.dll` is dependent upon another library and that library exists both in `netcoreapp2.0` and in `Publish` folder. Why is it that `dotnet` can load it from one folder, and can't load it from another folder? How do I debug this?

Comment: do you have Project.Dll `CopyToLocal` set to `true or false`? also make sure that it's not pointing to the `release folder also

Comment: Do you really mean to debug? Or running the app?

Comment: Are you going to debug the problem that "Why is it that dotnet can load it from one folder, and can't load it from another folder"? If you want to debug the application, just call `dotnet run` in `D:\Project`.

Comment: What does it say when it "break"?

Comment: @MethodMan, all of my DLLs are set to copy local, and `Project.dll` and the other library, say `OtherLibrary.dll` is also set to copy local. And they are also available all in Debug folder

Comment: @ibubi, what do you mean? The problem here is the deployment model. `netcoreapp2.0` should act as a deployed folder in itself. Yet it complains that it can't load `OtherLibrary.dll`

Comment: @HenkMollema, the same error that we would get on old MVC frameworks, that would require us to turn on bindings in registry to find out what dependency chain is traversed and what assembly is the caller, and stuff like that. Yet here, we don't have access to that option. Just `FileNotFound` exception.

Comment: Do the `verbose` or `diagnostic` flags help diagnose the problem? See [dotnet command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore2x)